# Output screen closes after pressing the enter

Tags: c++

I have below program written in c++.

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main() {
    int age = 0;
    cout<<"Please enter age\n";
    cin>>age;
    cout<<"Your age is - ";
    cout<<age;
}
```

After entering the age, it closes the screen. I can't see the output. I could it by pressing the Alt + F5 only.

Is it possible to check the output right after entering the age by pressing the enter key?

Comment: I guess it is more a windows problem than c++; try launching your program from a console manually or ask for the terminal not to close when finished

Comment: Run the program from terminal or command prompt

Comment: That's the normal behavior of console applications being run from a GUI.Interactive console programs aren't really intended to run directly from a GUI environment, instead they are intended to be run from an already open console or terminal program (like the "Command Prompt").

Comment: Just as an FYI, `iostream.h` has been gone for a long time and you might be running a very outdated compiler (you won't be learning standard C++).

Comment: However, you *could* ask the user to press the `Enter` key to exit, and then read a line (discarding all input) until you get a newline. But that will affect the running behavior of your program when run from a console as well, as then the user still have to press the `Enter` key to exit.

Comment: That's the normal behavior of console applications being run from a GUI... **on Windows**.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the user to press enter or type a certain character to exit.

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main() {
    int age = 0;
    cout<<"Please enter age\n";
    cin>>age;
    cout<<"Your age is - ";
    cout<<age;
    cin.get();
}
```

**Note1:** Avoid system("PAUSE") --> [system("pause"); - Why is it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1107705/13695921)

**Note2** In some IDE's like codeblocks the behaviour change.

CodeBlocks will wait for you to press any key before closing to output screen even if `main` returns 0

Answer (score 0):

Adding this file: `#include<conio.h>` worked for me.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main() {
    int age = 0;
    cout<<"Please enter age\n";
    cin>>age;
    cout<<"Your age is - ";
    cout<<age;
    getch();
}
```